# Javascript loop to repeat query for each element

Tags: javascript, html, loops, web-scraping

I have a website that contains multiple class elements with the same name.
If I run

```
var z = document.getElementsByClassName('DivContainerV2');
```

I get 69 elements

```
0: div.DivContainerV2
1: div.DivContainerV2
2: div.DivContainerV2
3: div.DivContainerV2
...
68: div.DivContainerV2
69: div.DivContainerV2
```

Each of them has a 'video count' class that I want to return it's value for.
I can this one by one like so, by changing the number in the square brackets:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('DivItemContainerV2')[0].getElementsByClassName('video-count')[0].innerText;

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('DivItemContainerV2')[1].getElementsByClassName('video-count')[0].innerText;

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('DivItemContainerV2')[2].getElementsByClassName('video-count')[0].innerText;

var a = document.getElementsByClassName('DivItemContainerV2')[3].getElementsByClassName('video-count')[0].innerText;
```

Is there a way to create a loop that repeats the query for n occurrences of the div class name?

I've tried this:

```
var a = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i <= z; i++) { 
  a = document.getElementsByClassName('DivItemContainerV2')[i].getElementsByClassName('video-count')[0].innerText
}
```

But I get an error: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsByClassName')

My expected output would be an array of the video counts:

```
a = ['2391', '29k', '194'...]
```

Comment: As a guess, you need `i < z` rather than `i <= z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with className `.DivContainerV2 .video-count` and then loop over and get the array of inner text value.

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as:

```js
const allVideoCountEl = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".DivContainerV2 .video-count"));

const innerValues = allVideoCountEl.map(videoCountEl => videoCountEl.innerText.trim())

console.log(innerValues)
```

```html
<div class="DivContainerV2">
  <div class="video-count">
    2391
  </div>
</div>
<div class="DivContainerV2">
  <div class="video-count">
    29k
  </div>
</div>
<div class="DivContainerV2">
  <div class="video-count">
    194
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as:

```js
const allVideoCountEl = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".DivContainerV2 .video-count"));

const innerValues = [];
allVideoCountEl.forEach(videoCountEl => {
  innerValues.push(videoCountEl.innerText.trim());
})

console.log(innerValues)
```

```html
<div class="DivContainerV2">
  <div class="video-count">
    First
  </div>
</div>
<div class="DivContainerV2">
  <div class="video-count">
    Second
  </div>
</div>
<div class="DivContainerV2">
  <div class="video-count">
    Third
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great, but how do i save it as a variable rather than the console log?

Comment: @DrPaulVella Example updated in sandbox and here check it

Comment: @DrPaulVella Create an array and just push it

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is a map and querySelectorAll which will select the counters. We need to wrap in a spread `[...<your collection/nodelist>]` to use array methods on it

```
var count = [...document.querySelectorAll('.DivContainerV2 .video-count')]
  .map(cnt => cnt.textContent.trim());
```

For more complex coding you can do

```js
var count = [...document.querySelectorAll('.DivItemContainerV2 .video-count')]
  .map(cnt => {
    const val = cnt.textContent.trim();
    const match = val.match(/(\d+)(\D+)/)
    if (match) {
      const [_, num, suffix] = match;
      const mult = { "k": 1000 }[suffix.toLowerCase()]; // add whatever needed
      return mult ? num * mult : +num;
    } else return +val
  });
console.log(count)
```

```html
<div class='DivItemContainerV2'>
  <div class='video-count'>2391</div>
</div>
<div class='DivItemContainerV2'>
  <div class='video-count'>29k</div>
</div>
<div class='DivItemContainerV2'>
  <div class='video-count'>194</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the push method of an array

```
var a = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i <= z; i++) { 
  a.push(document.getElementsByClassName('DivItemContainerV2')[i].getElementsByClassName('video-count')[0].innerText);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its a good start.

If you get `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getElementsByClassName')`. Then the element before `getElementsByClassName` is not defined. So probably [i], since the document is probably defined. I'm guessing i is out of reach, so your Z is too high.

What is your Z here? How many items do you want to get? If you write 3 you should get 0-3, so four items.

You are also re-assigning A to be the element, if you want all elements to be added you can use push, or a spread operator if you will get an array of items.

So

```
var a = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i <= z; i++) { 
  a = [...a, ...document.getElementsByClassName('DivItemContainerV2')[i].getElementsByClassName('video-count')[0].innerText]
}
```

Comment: No JS collection or array goes from 0 to length. Always length-1.